# iBeacon advertising on Android

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon

I am trying, with my nexus 6P, to advertise an ibeacon. The format it seems correct but the signal is recognised by Android app and not from iPhone app. Do you know if there are some limitation?

Comment: Note that your proposed edit to my answer below was rejected, because the edit should have been made to the question.  Based on the info in the proposed edit, however, I have augmented my answer to include a note about setting the manufacturer id properly.  Please note that addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nexus 6P supports BLE advertising, and you can make it transmit any known format for which you have the proper formula.  You might want to try an off-the-shelf beacon transmitter app like [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en), which allows you to choose several formats, and see if your receiving device can pick up its transmission.

If the iOS device does not pick up the transmission, **make sure the iOS device has been configured to range for the specific ProximityUUID that beacon is transmitting.**  Remember that iOS will not pick up all iBeacon transmissions -- it has to be pre-configured with the ProximityUUID first.

If you can make the iOS device pick up the Locate beacon transmission, but you can't make it pick up the transmission from your program, there may be an issue with the beacon format it is transmitting.  Posting the code will help track that down.

Also, **make very sure you set the BLE manufacturer code properly** in the advertisement.  iOS is very picky about the manufacturer code used when deciding whether to recognize a beacon advertisement.  The Bluetooth SIG company code for Google may be appropriate for Eddystone beacons, but it should not be used for other beacon types they did not sponsor.